# Что надо прописать в .htaccess, чтобы файлы без расширения парсились как html файлы?

Tags: .htaccess, файлы

Что надо прописать в `.htaccess`, чтобы файлы без расширения парсились как *html*-файлы?

Comment: Примерно это делается так (с помощью mod_rewrite), приведенный пример скорее всего не рабочий, времени нет читать маны и тестировать, поправьте кому не лень.  

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^([^.]+)$
    RewriteRule $1 [L,T=text/html]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Location /html>
  ForceType text/html
</Location>
```

Для всех файлов без расширения:

```
<FilesMatch "^[^\.]+$">
    ForceType text/html
</FilesMatch>
```

[docs>>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#forcetype)

Comment: +100[]()[]()

Comment: inso, спасибо, всё заработало